# For loop execution with list range

Tags: python, for-loop

I am creating a list of positive integers from user input. The list will have 5 values. in case of a negative input, that value will not go to the list and issue an error massage and ask for the number again.
The issue I am having with my code is the loop is dropping after 5 execution. whereas, I want it to keep running untill I am getting 5 positive inetegers.

```
lists = []

for i in range(5):
  s = int(input('Enter a number: '))
  if s >= 0:
    lists.append(s)
  else:
    print("Enter a valid number")

print(lists)
```

Answer (score 5):

You would better change it to a while loop, like below:

```
lists = []

while len(lists)<5:
    s = int(input('Enter a number: '))
    if int(s) >= 0:
        lists.append(int(s))
    else:
        print("Enter a valid number")
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the while loop instead of the for loop:

```
while len(lists)<5:
  s = int(input('Enter a number: '))
  if s >= 0:
    lists.append(s)
  else:
    print("Enter a valid number")
```

For loop is better suited for a known number of iterations, and while loop will check for a condition before it is executed.